# My eye won't track to my bone on a certain axis?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, rigging

When I added an object constraint to my eye mesh, I selected my armature as my target and my bone as the one that I want my eye to track to, but it's not working.

Here's what it looks like:[image]

And every time I move my bone, the eye doesn't track to it. That's mainly because that if you look right below the Head/Tail bar, you'll see an axis selection where the eye wants to focus the bone on a certain axis. For whatever reason, it'll track the bone when I select the X and X-, Y and Y-, but not Z and Z-, and that's where I want it to be because it'll place it on the original position it was in. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Uploading the .blend file might help get more accurate answers, you can upload the file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Additionally, I can see many issues in the attached image, first of all, it's better to use Quaternion instead of Euler to avoid Gimbal lock, that's in the rotation method for the eye and the bone, second, I believe you should use Local Space rather than World space in the Track To constraint, and I believe you should check the Target checkbox.

Comment: I don't see where I would change Quaternion to Euler, you're going to have to tell me where exactly it is. Second, which one should would I have to change world space to Local space, Left or right?

Comment: Also here's the Blend File

Comment: Where's the .blend file? After uploading it, follow the instructions, you should copy the link, edit your question, paste the link in it, then save your edit. Concerning Euler, look in the properties panel (the one that you toggle using N keyboard shortcut) under Transform > Rotation, you can change the (XYZEuler) to (Quaternion).

Comment: Sorry accidentally clicked post before I could get the file onto the comment or question. :/

Comment: The file should be on my question now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your case is very simple, keep everything as is, use world space in the Track To constraint for both, the only thing you need to change is the (To: -Y) in the Track constraint. Which is the Y axis for the Bone.
Aside from that, you have some issues in the file, you have 4 armatures, each has bones, and all of them have default names, my advise is that you rename your bones, delete unused armature, this will make your work much easier, I also had to move the origin of the eye to it's bottom rather than the center so it doesn't detach from it's joint when rotates.
Here's the .blend file:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well all the other armatures and models are for my project, but other than that, it should be good.

Comment: Yeah at least rename them, this will make your life much easier, if this answers your question, please mark it as answered, unless you're looking for a different answer, or you think this answer isn't complete